# Windows 10 Laptop volume glitch

Tags: windows-10, audio

During night I turn my volume up all the way for my alarms and this morning it glitched, as well as a few days ago.

I'll press the button and it'll go slow. When I stop pressing the button it keeps getting louder until it gets to 100%. Then I try to turn it down, and it keeps getting louder and louder until I restart my laptop. Vice versa, if I'm holding the lower volume button and then release it, it'll keep going down until it mutes.

The only way I know to fix it is by restarting.  It's a huge pain in the neck and I'd like to know if there's a way to fix it.

Comment: Does the same issue happen if you use the software to change the volume? It sounds like (no pun) the issue is the hardware (the buttons)

Answer (score 0):

There have been a number of issues with sound volume that some users experienced after some Windows 10 updates. My PC would lose the volume setting, so that t returned to 50% after reboot.

A number of sound device manufacturers have released new drivers to accommodate Windows 10. [MS suggests updating drivers (which fixed the issue I experienced).](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/instantanswers/a183aa8b-0eac-4566-867a-98d2761a770d/fix-sound-problems)

- Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type *Device Manager* to run the application.
- Right-click on *Sound, video and game controllers*.
- Select *Update Driver Software...*
- Click *Search automatically for updated driver software*.

If that does not fix the issue, go directly to the manufacturer's web site to look for new drivers. *Do not* download them from a third party, though, as those might be malware.